# If a power series is of finite degree but infinitely many variables is it classed as a polynomial?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

For example, is $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots$ a polynomial or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a polynomial has finitely many terms (even if it lives in a ring with infinitely many variables).  So, typically, this would not be a polynomial.

You could generalize/adapt the definition to allow this case, but you might need to re-prove/generalize certain theorems in this context (especially if you are not working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).